# Is it possible to decrypt messages of a communication over ssl

Tags: security, ssl, https, wireshark

There is such a windows application that communications with the server through https protocol, it is an auction tool and works only several hours per month. I have captured network packets (by windows network monitor) during one auction.

I am wondering whether it is possible to mimic this client, by analyzing the the packets I collected (or any packets I could collect in future auctions). I know from this wireshark artical "[Secure Socket Layer (SSL)](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL)" that it should be possible (and without much effort) to descypt the entrypted messages from server, **but how? And is it possible to dectrypt the messages sent by client to server, too?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the whole reasoning behind SSL is that third party listeners who are trying to receive and decrypt packets between your client and the server won't be able to do so. The packets that your clients send will be encrypted and the server will need the appropriate key to decrypt the message which you could then analyze using wireshark. This [article](http://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/) does a good job of explaining how HTTPS works. To answer your questions:

```
 Is it possible to mimic the client of a https web service
```

Yep, this is available in a lot of different tools. A popular tool you could implement this with is called Jmeter. This [article](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterAndHTTPS) explains how you can send HTTPS requests to your server. Once you exchange the key pairs between your client (JMeter in this case) you will be able to decrypt messages on both ends which have been sent in an encrypted format over the wire.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I investigated some about how ssl works. Based on that investigation, I know it could be easy to decrypt messages sent from server, but hard for the other direction. So my question includes whether it could be possible to analyze the the messages that are used to communitate, and then use that knowledge to create a program that does the same. I will take a look at Jmeter you mentioned, but If you know it, does it based on the assumption that I have already known the messages used??

Comment: So you can't "analyze the the messages that are used to communitate to create a program" because all that information is heavily encrypted in at least 128-bit keys. As you can read from here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951386/how-secure-is-ssl) it would take longer than our existence to decrypt those messages. You need two partners, both whom have keys and that have been appropriately traded in order to send information over SSL which can be decrypted and analyzed.

Comment: You can't analyze the encrypted message because it will literally mean nothing, there are no obvious patterns in the text for you to infer upon. Please let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Also, just for clarification, JMeter will have a key that it's traded with your server. And based off of that key, an encryption algorithm is run on your packets before they are sent over to the server. The server will use that key to decrypt the messages. Please let me know if you have any questions!